# How to write a Makefile that rebuilds targets when a script they use but don't build is modified?

Tags: makefile, dependencies

For example, consider the following Makefile:

```
all: obj.bin
    ./script.sh obj.bin $@
%.bin: %.o
[...]
```

In this case, make will rebuild the project when the source file(s) for `obj.bin` change, but not when `script.sh` is modified, even though the final output depends on it.

Comment: You should just declare that the target `all` has a dependency on the `./script.sh` file.  Is there more to it?

Comment: I'm missing it, @MadScientist.  Presumably, `all` is the default target, so it will run anyway unless the user specifies a different target explicitly.  On the other hand, `all` depending on the script does not cause `obj.bin` to depend on the script.

Comment: More generally, I think the details of this question fail to capture the true intent.  Supposing that there is no regular file named `all` in the working directory or that target `all` is declared `.PHONY`, the command `make all` will result `make` running the command `./script.sh obj.bin all`, regardless of the state of file `./script.sh`, unless file `obj.bin` is out of date and cannot be built.  If `all` is the default target, as would be conventional, then a plain `make` command would have the same effect.  A [mre] would be appropriate here.

Comment: Perhaps you have simply confused us (me, anyway) by using the target name `all` in an unconventional manner.  Is that supposed to be the name of a built file?

Comment: I assumed that since `$@` appeared in the script, the recipe actually created that filename.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that you are using `all` in the usual `make` style as a `.PHONY` target. Otherwise this question makes hardly sense, simply make `all` depend on `script.sh`.

Your problem then, is two-fold: the conventional `all` target (in a small, conventional `makefile`) is the vertex in the dependency tree where all paths from all prerequisites finally end. In plain english, the rule `all: foo.exe foo_test.exe` expresses that you are good when `foo.exe` and `foo_test.exe` are younger than all of their own prerequisites. The thing to note here is that `all` has - and needs - no further explicit command because the  *-action-*, namely *"go and update foo.exe und foo_test.exe (recursively) if needed"* is the **main intrinsic principle of action** of `make` - no need to state this explicitly. Long story short, `all` usually has no recipe commands.

The second problem was that your `makefile` does not catch the **complete** dependency tree. Obviously there seems to exist another output which is "created" (bear with me) by runnnig `./script.sh obj.bin $@` *and this would be the true final target* which you then could rightfully depend on `script.sh`. That you didn't include it in your `makefile` makes me assume that your true output may be something transient (e.g. only a screen message), or some change recorded elsewhere, where `make` can't see it. This is a principal shortcoming of `make` and relatives which allow only file system elements as nodes in the dependency tree (or `.PHONY` targets which act like shortcuts in it). Either you create an artificial element, that is a `touch lastrun.txt` and move the `all` target down to the new root of the dependencies or you devise a method to generate some time-stampable file from running `script.sh` which is not an arbitrary ugliness like the former.

Comment: The question makes even less sense if `all` is `.PHONY`.  In that case, `all` will be considered out of date on every run, even if the script *hasn't* changed -- just the opposite of the problem the OP describes.

Comment: You're right, I needed to make `all` depend on `script.sh`. In my actual Makefile, `all` makes another file which is generated by `script.sh`. Both my question and the example were a result of me misunderstanding what Makefile rules do. Sorry.

Comment: @JohnBollinger you are right -  I forgot that `all` has no recipe usually. Will try to correct the wording.

Answer (score 1):

After considering the question for some time, I can make sense of it only by interpreting target name `all` as the name of an actual file to be built. If it were an artificial target, and especially if it were formally declared `.PHONY`, then the problem described would not arise (but different ones might do).

Such use would run counter to long-established convention for target name "`all`", but it is consistent with the example rule presented:

> ```
> all: obj.bin
>     ./script.sh obj.bin $@
> ```

Why else would it make sense to use special variable `$@` in the recipe?

---

So let's suppose that you want to give `make` a rule for building a file, say `my_target`, whose recipe will run if and only if anything needs to be done.  The question, then, is how can `make` recognize whether anything needs to be done?

`make` answers that question for targets that already exist (and are not declared `.PHONY`) by comparing the target's timestamp with those of the declared prerequisites.  Prerequisites can be files that are targets of other `make` rules, but frequently they are not.  For example, C and C++ source files are frequent prerequisites of `make` rules, but rarely are they themselves built files.

However, the specific nature of the dependency is irrelevant.  `make` does not know about source files, object files, libraries, or executables.  It's much simpler than that.  Everything `make` knows about dependencies between targets and their prerequisites comes from the declaration sections (not the recipes) of the applicable rules.

If the content of `my_target` varies meaningfully with changes to some local `./script.sh`, then the script is a logical prerequisite of that target, but `make` knows about that only if you tell it so explcitly.  Something like this, for example:

```
# Use script.sh to build my_target from obj.bin
my_target: ./script.sh obj.bin
        ./script.sh obj.bin $@
```